# Stacking components in circuitikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I wanna draw some schematics, but I need voltage and current sources quite different from those provided by package.

[image: sources]

I think I can use american current source with empty source to get my current souce and just american current source as my voltage source.

```
\begin{circuitikz}[american voltages, american currents, european resistors]
\draw 
(0,0) to[voltmeter, rotate=0] (0,4)
      to[ammeter] (4,4) -- (4,0)
      to[I,/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=1cm, n=S1] (0,0)
      to [esource,/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=2cm] (0,0)
;
\end{circuitikz}
```

But I'm getting this:

[image: Schmtc]

Do you have any idea to overlap one component with another or better, write a macro to automate this?

Answer (score 2):

Your example fails because the first generator is drawn between `(4,0)` and `(0,0)` (so at `(2,0)`) while the second one is from `(0,0)` to `(0,0)`... 
Use two different paths:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[american voltages, american currents, european resistors]
\path (4,0) to[I,/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=1cm, n=S1] (0,0);
\draw (4,0) to [esource,/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=2cm] (0,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: strange current source]

...and the `\path` instead of `\draw` will avoid the wires from "sticking into" the empty generator.

Comment: Can you explain to me how this code can be fixed? `\newcommand{\I_source}[3]
{\path[rotate=#3] (#1) to[I,/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=1cm] (#2);
\draw (#1) to [esource,/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=2cm] (#2);}`

Comment: You can't use the underscore in the command name...

Comment: Is it really worth it learning Circuitikz? Because it seems that I would save a lot of time using another tool like Visuo and then copy the image to LaTeX...

Comment: @JoãoPedro it depends. If you need to produce lot of circuits with small differences (and if you like the way it marks voltages and current, which I don't), probably yes. Otherwise, my vote on the faster and best-looking application for drawing circuits goes to [XCircuit](http://opencircuitdesign.com/xcircuit/)